# LND How to reset pending_open_channels?

Tags: bitcoind, mempool, lightning-network-daemon

I am using LND (most recent version 0.6.1-beta) and I have a lot of pending channels in state
`pending_open_channels` 
which are stuck for many days (perhaps because of low fee and  full mempool) so I want to reset those transactions from my LND/bitcoind or just increase a fee so that could be mined and the channel open.

What options do I have? Can I just delete/reset all pending channels somehow? Or wait or what.

Many thanks for your attention and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoind v0.18 was unable to broadcasst my channel transactions because of bug in LND. This error has been found in lnd log:

`Second argument must be numeric (maxfeerate) and no longer supports a boolean. To allow a transaction with high fees, set maxfeerate to 0.`

https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/2961

I have downgraded bitcoind and the stuck transactions moved.

Comment: Good that you worked around the problem, but it's still a great question in need of a real answer.  Perhaps un-accept your own reply?